# Pass parameters with apostrophs to a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

How do I passt following parameters to my batch file?

```
custom.bat mode="test" logs="true"
```

I tried to double the `"` but nothing helped.

Comment: You should mention that you can not change the `custom.bat` file. And you should explain what you expect from custom.bat to handle your parameters and show the code that fetches the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
custom.bat "mode="test"" "logs="true""
```

And, in `custom.bat` you remove the unneeded quotes

```
@echo off
    set "arg1=%~1"
    set "arg2=%~2"

    echo [%arg1%] [%arg2%]
```

Comment: I cannot change the custom.bat application... Is there another way.. like to write your own bat file calling costom.bat?

Comment: @devhedgehog, if you can not change the batch file, can you post a sample of how if handles the arguments?

Answer (score -1):

You may use CALL command to launch a new batch-file. After executing the last line of the "called file", the control will return back to the "calling file".
You may set the parameters to the "called .bat fie" by using either a simple string or a variable.
eg.
CALL MyScript.bat "1234"
or
SET _MyVar="1234"
CALL MyScript.bat %_MyVar%

As a precaution, you may use SETLOCAL & ENDLOCAL to keep separation between variables of same-name among different files.

Comment: Thanks but where is here the explaination how to use apostroph?

Comment: I assume that you mean double-quotes (") when you mention apostroph.  If you are sending the parameters directly, then you use enclose them within the double-quotes. Otherwise, if you use a variable, then you use double-quotes to set its value. However, in this case, you do not need to enclose the variable-name  (while passing as parameter) within quotes. It needs to be enclosed within %    Hope it helps.  I do request you to reverse the "downgrade'; since I am trying to help you to solve your problem issue.

Comment: You may obtain further info on CALL command (which you may use to pass parameters from one file to another) at https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true